# Unable to Connect with my Database 000webhost.com

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
  try {
        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://sql4.000webhost.com/a7291194_xxx";
        Connection connection = null; 
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance(); 
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "a7291194_xxx", "xxx");
        if(!connection.isClosed())
             System.out.println("Successfully connected to " + "MySQL server using TCP/IP...");
        connection.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        System.out.println("Unable to connect to database"+ex);
    }
```

With the following connector code I am trying to connect with the database on 000webhost.com but it gives me an error:

```
    CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

    The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
    The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

I am trying my best for the first time as I am totally new to webhosting so please help me thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you ping port 3306 on that particular host?

Comment: no problem its just a sample db i just need to know how can i connect with it>?

Comment: Check if there is any firewall that might be preventing connections on the port.

Comment: first of all check it the specified host database allows remote connection

Answer (score 0):

its same either on your local or on server

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://DomainName OR IP:3306/databasename", "username", "password");
```

Comment: i want to connect with the server

Answer (score 0):

At 000webhost.com remote MySQL connections are disabled for security and server performance reasons. 
If you upgrade your account,  MySQL connections will be enabled.